# /connect/userinfo returns me a 403 forbidden in identityserver4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using the sample application available with IdentityServer4 : Quickstart6_AspNetIdentity.sln
Using the ro.client, I am able to get the token.

[image]

But when I am using the same token to get the userinfo, I am getting 403 Forbidden error in the same sample. Using the sample as it is.
Don't know if it is a bug or I am missing something in the parameters. Following all the parameters as mentioned in the document:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Was missing the scope=openid while generating the token. It works fine now.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem as you. I have a client that must validate token only with password and user. Where exactly do you have to put the scope configuration? Because if it is where the client configuration is, then I throw an error if I do that.